# Launch activity automatically after Google Sign In - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity, google-signin

I'm trying to achieve something pretty simple since the last few days, but I didn't make it.

Basically, I used the sample app from Google Developers to create a login process for my app. I managed to login from Google when the Sign In button is clicked, and also to know if a user has already logged in and authenticated my app.

What I want to do is the following: when a user launches my app and is already logged in, I want to skip the login screen and automatically go to the next activity.

I made a bunch of tests but I will not post everything I tried here because it was sometimes pretty messy. Here the code I used for now:

My MainActivity.java:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        View.OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = "SignInActivity";
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Button listeners
        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);

        // [START configure_signin]
        // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
        // profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        // [END configure_signin]

        // [START build_client]
        // Build a GoogleApiClient with access to the Google Sign-In API and the
        // options specified by gso.
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();
        // [END build_client]

        // [START customize_button]
        // Customize sign-in button. The sign-in button can be displayed in
        // multiple sizes and color schemes. It can also be contextually
        // rendered based on the requested scopes. For example. a red button may
        // be displayed when Google+ scopes are requested, but a white button
        // may be displayed when only basic profile is requested. Try adding the
        // Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN scope to the GoogleSignInOptions to see the
        // difference.
        SignInButton signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
        signInButton.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());
        // [END customize_button]
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (opr.isDone()) {
            // If the user's cached credentials are valid, the OptionalPendingResult will be "done"
            // and the GoogleSignInResult will be available instantly.
            Log.d(TAG, "Got cached sign-in");
            GoogleSignInResult result = opr.get();
            handleSignInResult(result);
        } else {
            // If the user has not previously signed in on this device or the sign-in has expired,
            // this asynchronous branch will attempt to sign in the user silently.  Cross-device
            // single sign-on will occur in this branch.
            showProgressDialog();
            opr.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
                    hideProgressDialog();
                    handleSignInResult(googleSignInResult);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    // [START onActivityResult]
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
        }
    }
    // [END onActivityResult]

    // [START handleSignInResult]
    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
            updateUI(true);

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SplashScreen.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
            finish();
        } else {
            // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
            updateUI(false);
        }
    }
    // [END handleSignInResult]

    // [START signIn]
    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }
    // [END signIn]

    // [START signOut]
    private void signOut() {
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {
                        // [START_EXCLUDE]
                        updateUI(false);
                        // [END_EXCLUDE]
                    }
                });
    }
    // [END signOut]

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        // An unresolvable error has occurred and Google APIs (including Sign-In) will not
        // be available.
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
    }

    private void showProgressDialog() {
        if (mProgressDialog == null) {
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            mProgressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.loading));
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        }

        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideProgressDialog() {
        if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
            mProgressDialog.hide();
        }
    }

    private void updateUI(boolean signedIn) {
        if (signedIn) {
            findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.sign_in_button:
                signIn();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

So my question is: how and where should I put my intent to go to the next activity?

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SplashScreen.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
```

Thank you very much for your help! Tell me if you need further details or explanations.

Comment: Save in your parameters file of the app a boolean that means if the user is logged in or not. So when you start agan just check that bool, if it's false do the login form, if not proced where you wanna go

Comment: In your `if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN)` condition, add your `intent`. Or put in `if (result.isSuccess())`.

Answer (score 0):

Put your activity class which you want to show after skipping login screen in `YourClassAfterLogin.class`

```
 private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
            Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
                GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
                updateUI(true);

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, YourClassAfterLogin.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
                finish();
            } else {
                // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
                updateUI(false);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 // [START handleSignInResult]
private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
        updateUI(true);

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SplashScreen.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
        finish();
    } else {
        // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
        updateUI(false);
```

at isSuccess you can put your intent..